# Why is VSCode keep warning me about include errors?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, stm32

When I'm programming on my STM32 project, VSCode constantly underlines the code `#include "main.h"` with the reason belows:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit.
> cannot open source file "stm32f1xx.h" (dependency of "main.h")

However, I double-checked my `c_cpp_properties.json`, finding nothing wrong with it. Meanwhile, VSCode has given me the quick fix method, adding `${workspaceFolder}/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F1xx/Include` to `includePath` parameter, which didn't work either.

Belows are my configurations.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "USE_HAL_DRIVER",
                "STM32F103xE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\\10 2021.07\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm"
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "USE_HAL_DRIVER",
                "STM32F103xE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "compilerPath": "/opt/ARM/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And the required file `/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F1xx/Include/stm32f1xx.h` does exist and the compilation with `make` can be done correctly too.

I've check the files multiple times but didn't find any problem, like belows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sTq0.png)

Comment: under which configuration do you need that path, Win32 or Linux? `/Drivers/...`looks like Linux, Is that the full path

Comment: `/Drivers/...` means the `Drivers` folder under the folder of the project, e.g. `STM32Project/Drivers/...`

Comment: Hi, Futurime, at first do you see that file in file explorer? I mean `main.h`?

Comment: ..and same question for that Drivers folder :)  I think you created project in Cube IDE or something and then didn't mark a check with copy neccessary files to folder so now you use them from another localization in disk.

Comment: I did mark the checkbox to copy files. I posted the screenshot of VSCode, in which the necessary files were.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell vscode where to find all the include files needed.
When you add an include folder to the `includePath`, the included headers inside the folder might include other header from elsewhere. This might explain why you still get the error after adding a single path to the `includePath`.

Project generated using CubeMX typically have multiple include folders.

Your configuration file should look something like that

```json
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/Core/Inc/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Drivers/CMSIS/Include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Include/**"
            ],
            "defines": ["STM32F031x6","USE_HAL_DRIVER"],
            "compilerPath": "path_to_compiler",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
```

To find the required folders, you have different to do it :

##### Using the Makefile

If you have a working Makefile, it probably contains a place where it defines the used header files, for example :

```
C_INCLUDES =  \
-IDrivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include
```

##### Using Vscode intellisense

If there is a missing header, Vscode will show the following error

```
cannot open source file "HEADER2.h" (dependency of "HEADER1.h")
```

This means that `HEADER2.h` is included inside `HEADER1.h` but there is no `HEADER2.h` in the `includePath`.

So you should find the folder containing `HEADER2.h` and add it.
To do so, you can use `find . -name "HEADER2.h"` from the root of the project.